# Objective-C with some Objective-C++, calling a normal c++ method "referenced from" problem

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I made an Objective-C project for the iPhone. I had only one cpp class, the soundEngine taken from some Apple demo. Now I'm trying to merge OpenFeint which is coded in Objective-C++. I dropped in the code, by simply dragging the files and just tick "Call C++ default ctors/dtors in Objective-C" in Project Settings. I am not even referring to it from my code. When I hit Build, my Objective-C code cannot find the methods of the cpp file.
All the class files compile, including OpenFeint's, but in the linking stage it says several of these errors:
"_SoundEngine_SetDisabled", referenced from: someClass.o

Note that it is adding an underscore in front of the methods when it's reporting these linking errors.

P.S. I know that for OpenFeint first thing one should do is convert the files to .mm but if possible I don't want to go down that road at this stage of development. I was going to try create a wrapper Objective-C++ class for it. I read someone managed to do that.

Comment: "Something like" isn't helpful. Post the actual linker errors as they're printed on the screen.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *"drop in the code"*?

Comment: That's the actual error but there are several of them which are the same so I didn't bother pasting the same errors. Let me edit

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying you have Objective-C++ files that are not `.mm` files, then they're not being read as Objective-C++ unless you've done something special to make it so. `.mm` is the extension for Objective-C++ files. That's why you've been advised to use it.

Comment: No I'm not saying that. Objective-C++ are .mm, Objective-C are .m and I have one pure C++ file as .cpp. And I cannot access the .cpp methods.

Comment: Cannot access the C++ methods from *where•? Anywhere? Their own class?

Comment: Anywhere... compiling works, linking no. And this used to work before I added Objective-C++.

Comment: Wait, calling a C++ method from Objective-C worked but calling it from Objective-C++ doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, that's the strange thing. I know its insane. At this point I'm thinking of dumping the cpp class and just use another Audio class from the iPhone framework like AVAudioPlayer

Answer (score 0):

> but in the linking stage it says several of these errors: "_SoundEngine_SetDisabled", referenced from: someClass.o

There's no [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B) on that method.  Is it declared as `extern "C"` in a header somewhere but defined as a C++ method/function.